# How to Parse parent-child related JsonArray in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

This is the Json text. I can get "name,surname and books" as an Array. But the problem is books also is an array.And the content of books is coming in this form ;`{"title:heresometext",paragraphs{value1:heresometext,value2:heresometext}}`  so it is like array in array. Like a parant-child relation. the thing i want to do is to reach thoose value1,value2,value3 strings seperated.

```html
{"data"
 [
  "name" : "Here some text",
  "surname" : "Here some text",
  "books" : [
  {
    "title1" : "Here some text.",
    "paragraphs" : [
    {
        "value1" : "Here some text."
    },
    {
        "value2" : "Here some text."
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title2" : "Here some text.",
    "paragraphs" : [
    {
        "value3" : "Here some text.",
        "image1" : "Here some text."
    },
    {
        "value4" : "Here some text."
    },
    {
        "value5" : "Here some text."
    }
    ]
  }
  ]
 ]
}
```

How can i get them like this form, in a tree form seperated all datas to be able to save them in a DB.
any help will be usefull

```html
  name: "Here some text",
  surname: "Here some text",
  books:
         - title1 : "Here some text."
             -paragraphs:
                 - value : "Here some text.
                 - value : "Here some text.
         - title2 : "Here some text."
             -paragraphs:
                 - value : "Here some text.
                 - image : "Here some text.
```

Answer (score 1):

We used [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) in our projects. It is a JSON Parser.

Example:

```
public class JSONParsingExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
      Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(parser.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jsondata.json").getFile()));
      JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
      JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
      JSONArray books = (JSONArray) data.get("books");
      System.out.println(books);
      Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = books.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject book = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("This books name is " + book.get("name"));
        JSONArray paras = (JSONArray) book.get("paras");
        Iterator<JSONObject> parasI = paras.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (parasI.hasNext()) {
          JSONObject para = (JSONObject) parasI.next();
          para.keySet().forEach(o -> System.out.println(o + "/" + para.get(o)));
        }
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am using the JSON.simple too, but i cannot reach to sub array

Comment: We can in our bachelor work, let me check tomorrow how we do it.

Comment: look, mine has 3 arrays; data[books [pharagraphs [, , , ]]]. i can reach books elements but the output is  {pharagraphs [, , ,]} and  not useful in this way

Comment: I adapted my example, hope this helps (Youll need JDK8+ or adapt the forEach to a for loop)